# How to write a multi table query with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables consume and recharge. how can i get the result?

consume table

```
user_name   date                consume 
a          12/12/2018 12:20       10    
a          12/12/2018 12:20       12    
a          1/1/2019 11:00         13
```

recharge table

```
user_name   date                recharge    
a          12/12/2018 12:20       20    
a          12/12/2018 12:20       30    
a          1/1/2019 11:00         40
```

result

```
user_name   date                  consume   recharge
a           12/12/2018 12:20        22        50
a           1/4/2019 12:20          13        40
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: look up "mysql join tables" and "group by"

Comment: date is a reserved word so whilst you can surround it in delimiters, it's not a good habit to get into.  Also the date value 1/4/2019 12:20 doesn't appear in your tables anywhere.

Comment: @ChrisFNZ `date` is not a reserved word.

Comment: @Barmar See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-D

Comment: @ChrisFNZ There's no `(R)` after `DATE` on that page. It's a keyword,  but not reserved. There's no problem using it as a column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a UNION ALL set operator to combine two sets, if the number of columns match and the datatypes are compatible

```
 SELECT c.user_name
      , c.date
      , c.consume
      , 0 AS recharge
   FROM consume c
  UNION ALL
 SELECT r.user_name
      , r.date
      , 0 AS consume
      , r.recharge
   FROM recharge r
```

We can wrap that in parens, and reference it like a table in an outer query.

The outer query can perform a GROUP BY operation to collapse the rows into groups, and we can use the SUM aggregate function to total up the values.

Something like this:

```
SELECT t.user_name 
     , t.date
     , SUM(t.consume)   AS consume
     , SUM(t.recharge)  AS recharge
  FROM ( -- inline view
         SELECT c.user_name
              , c.date
              , c.consume
              , 0 AS recharge
           FROM consume c
          UNION ALL
         SELECT r.user_name
              , r.date
              , 0 AS consume
              , r.recharge
           FROM recharge r
       ) t 
 GROUP 
    BY t.user_name 
     , t.date
```

This is workable for reasonably sized sets. For large number of rows, itgerlarge

There are other possible query patterns. The approach shown here is workable for trivial sets, and for some reasonably sized sets. We get into some performance issues with Hugh-Jass sets.

To clarify the specification... what do we want to return if there are rows in `recharge` with no matching rows in `consume`? And vice versa?  Do we want to omit those rows, or include them?